# Difference between similar curried types in Scala

Tags: scala

What is the difference between the types of the following two functions?

```
def add1: Int => Int => Int = a => b => a + b
def add2(a: Int)(b: Int) = a + b
```

Based on their declarations, they seem to have the same type.  Both are called in the same way:

```
scala> add1(1)(2)
res2: Int = 3

scala> add2(1)(2)
res3: Int = 3
```

However, there is an apparent difference in their types:

```
scala> :t add1
Int => Int => Int

scala> :t add2
(a: Int)(b: Int)Int
```

Additionally, partial application of `add1` is a bit cleaner than of `add2`.

```
scala> add1(1)
res4: Int => Int = <function1>

scala> add2(1)(_)
res5: Int => Int = <function1>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`add1` is a method with no parameters that returns a `Function1[Int, Function1[Int, Int]]`. `add2` is a method that takes two parameter lists and returns an `Int`.

Further reading:

[Difference between method and function in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2529184/difference-between-method-and-function-in-scala)

Answer (score 1):

There certainly is a difference between the two definitions.  Consider passing each a single argument.

```
add1(1)
(Int) => Int = <function1>

add2(1)
<console>:9: error: missing arguments for method add2 in object $iw;
follow this method with `_' if you want to treat it as a partially applied function
       add2(1)
```

However, if you partially apply add2 it has the same type as add1.

```
scala> :t add1
(Int) => (Int) => Int

scala> :t add2 _
(Int) => (Int) => Int
```

I understand add1 perfectly well.  It's an anonymous function that takes an Int and returns and Int=>Int.  This is the classic definition of a curried function.

I need to do more reading before I understand add2 perfectly well.  As far as I can tell, it's a method of writing functions that take their parameters in a different form (i.e. `add2(1)(2)`) and can easily be transformed into a curried function (`add2 _`).

Hope this helps!  I also look forward to a better explanation about `add2`.

Edit: this is a great document about curried methods in scala: http://www.codecommit.com/blog/scala/function-currying-in-scala

Answer (score 1):

`x.add1` is a function `Int => Int => Int`.

`x.add2` is a method, which is not a value and doesn't have the same type as `add1`. To get an object equivalent to `x.add1`, you have to use `x.add2 _`.